# Chrome mobile app not sending forms

Tags: html, google-chrome, brackets

I'm having this issue with a form I just created on my website. This is the first website I ever created and put online zo there might be some errors in it.

The issue I have is that the Chrome app on my Samsung Galaxy doesn't open my Mail app when I press 'send', but it does on Opera, Firefox, Safari and my standard Samsung Internet browser...

This is my HTML code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:myemailaddress@msn.com?subject=Portfolio" autocomplete="on" enctype="text/plain">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="6u 12u$(mobile)"><input class = "input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /></div>
                                <div class="6u$ 12u$(mobile)"><input class = "input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" /></div>
                                <div class="12u$ 12u$(mobile)"><input class = "input" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" /></div>
                                <div class="12u$">
                                <textarea class = "input" name="message" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class ="formtext" id="formtext">
                                * indicates a required field.
                                    ** This form might not work on the Chrome mobile application.
                                    </div>
                                <div class="12u$">
                                    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send">
                                    <input id="reset_button" type="reset" value="Reset">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Is this enough info?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the user's browser doesn't recognise the mailto action.

Why would that be?

Well, mailto is not an officially defined protocol. There is no established action for the browser to take with that type of link. Most browsers will recognise it, but since it's undefined, you're taking a chance there. If the browser doesn't recognise it, the user may simply get an error message. In some other instances, the user's e-mail program might open a new e-mail message requiring them to manually send it. That e-mail message may, or may not have the form data included. In fact, some will just open a new blank e-mail message! Or what about those hidden fields.

So, I would recommend not to use mailto.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there anything you can recommend? I'm still in my first year so I don't know that much yet.

Comment: you can use javascript to do the same. Check this: https://www.formget.com/javascript-submit-form/